# How to insert variable into methods with Databricks using PySpark

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

The title of this question is terrible, as I couldn't find the correct words to describe exactly what I would like in a sentence.

Anyway, I have a variable which returns two values separated by a comma, see below:

[image]

At the moment I'm reading in a database in Databricks as follows, `df = spark.table("samples.cdcTest.cdcmergetest")`

I would like to use the variable 'regName' instead of typing cdcTest.cdcmergetest.

I have tried the followiong:

```
df = spark.table("samples".regName)
```

But I get the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regName'`

I also trid the following

[image]

This looks like an indexing and slicing issue, but not sure

Ok, I've tried a few things that appear to be getting me closer to my goal see below
[image]

The problem I have is combining all the parts together:

df = spark.table("samples",db_name,table_name)

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple possibilities to generate a full name:

- Just concatenate names: `"samples" + "." + regName`
- Use f-strings `f"samples.{regName}"
- join the list: `".".join(["samples",db_name,table_name])`